# $R[X]$ is a principal ideal ring if and only if $R\cong R_{1}\oplus R_{2}\oplus\cdots \oplus R_{n}$,where each $R_{i}$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have read from the Gallian's abstract algebra textbook the following result

> $R[X]$ is a principal ideal ring if and only if $R\cong R_{1}\oplus R_{2}\oplus\cdots \oplus R_{n}$, where each $R_{i}$ is a field.

which the book said it was proved by undergraduates. And I try to prove it on my own, but it resists all my attempts. I try to seek the original paper on Internet, but I haven't got a clue. I am eager to know how to prove it. Any help or hint will be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91587/ring-of-polynomials-is-a-principal-ideal-ring-implies-coefficient-ring-is-a-fiel, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361258

Comment: Thank you,although I can't fully understand the profound conclusions your link links.I mean,is there an elementary proof of that? Thanks.

Comment: Principal ideal RING,not Domain.